# QGIS Qt Designer set current date and time in mask

Tags: qgis, qt-designer, datetime

I have created an input mask for QGIS using the Qt Designer. Everything works fine but I have a small issue with the date, the time and the date/time edit widget. Is there any way to display the current date or time in this fields? when using the default form from QGIS it displays the current date or time. When using a mask from Qt Designer the date is always 01.01.2000 and the time is 00:00:00, which are the default settings for the widgets in the Qt designer. I think there must be a setting inside Qt which I haven't found yet.

Using QGIS 2.12 and 2.14 with Windows 7 and Windows 10. Always the same.

Best regards